# Share custom exceptions through the several nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nuget

I have a project that contains five independent NuGet packages. These packages are wrappers under REST API. So they can throw similar exceptions connected with HTTP errors. I want to make custom exceptions at least under the HTTP errors.

Next, my packages are independent, to implement my idea I can't duplicate all custom exceptions classes in every package - because these will be different classes.

I think one that can help me is to create an additional NuGet package - MyPackage.Common and move shared exception classes to this package and make dependency from all other packages.

Is it the only approach? Perhaps there is another way to implement what I want?

Comment: _"I think one that can help me is to create an additional NuGet package"_ - that's the way to go.

Comment: Maybe the exceptions are not the only thing in this common package. Maybe there are other things than can go in there as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You suggestion is correct. You create a new library and deploy that as a NuGet package separately. Other projects reference that NuGet package and you're good to go.